# Django Rest queryset filter by url parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to filter queryset in ListAPIView depending on url parameter. Basically, application lists all attendees (User) of an event with a call to API like `/events/:id/attendees/`

You can find serializers, models, urls and views below. I also wonder any other practices to do such end-point implementation in Django REST

```
**serializers.py**
class AttendeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = ('user', 'status')


**views.py**
class EventAttendeeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Attendee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendeeSerializer
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # It should filter attendees by event_id posted in URL
        return Attendee.objects.all()

**urls.py**

url(r'^events/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/attendees/$', views.EventAttendeeList.as_view()),


**models.py**
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Attendee', related_name='attendees_event')


class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="a_event")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="a_user")
    requested_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can access the url parameter in your view with `self.kwargs['parameter_name']` ( http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-the-url ). So the simplest solution would be

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Attendee.objects.filter(event=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('pk', None) is a better usage: Thanks for the link

Comment: Sorry, QUERY_PARAMS not working in this case. I'm also looking for any other approaches like changing URL structure or serializers...