# How to filter Django REST Api

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have url:

```
path('api/theatre_screening_list/<int:theatre>', cinema.apiviews.TheatreScreeningList.as_view()),
```

with a view:

```
class TheatreScreeningList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Screening.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScreeningSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ("screen", "film", "date", "time")
```

and a serialiser:

```
class ScreeningSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Screening
        fields = ('id', 'screen','film','date','time')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        screen = Screen.objects.get(id=data['screen'])
        data['screen'] = f"{screen}"
        film = Film.objects.get(id=data['film'])
        data['film'] = f"{film}"
        return data
```

The screening class is:

```
class Screening(models.Model):
    screen = models.ForeignKey(Screen, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allocation')
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='screening')
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.screen.theatre.name}, {self.screen.name}, {self.date}, {self.time}, {self.film.title}, {self.film.rating}"
```

I am not sure where, or how, to filter the query so that I am only receiving data for the theatre specified in url. Could anyone suggest how to go about it?
thanks

Comment: Currently you use a ListAPIView which will only respond with the total list of all Entities. ListAPIView is in the end only a shortcut of the GenericAPIView and the ListModelMixin. For receiving a single entitiy specified in the url you need also use the RetrieveModelMixin. Depening on how many REST Methods you might want to use you also might want to look into view sets that combine multiple rest operation into one view definition.

Comment: Looking at the docs for RetrieveModelMixin it seems to get a single instance, what I want is a filtered list. But I will look at it further in case i have missed something. many thanks

Comment: Ah sorry for the misunderstanding. Then you have to look into the queryset or the get_queryset function (they are inter changable) sitting in the view. That decides the scope of the data of the view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460405/django-rest-queryset-filter-by-url-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can just override `get_queryset()` to filter against the  url:

```py
class TheatreScreeningList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ScreeningSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ("screen", "film", "date", "time")

    def get_queryset(self)
        theatre_id= self.kwargs['theatre']
        return Screening.objects.filter(screen__theatre__pk=theatre_id)
```